# Unable to open IE11 driver instance using Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\Users\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.45.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    
    driver.get("http://xxx");
```

Shows error while executing above code:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones.
>
> Enable Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
> Command duration or timeout: 1.33 seconds

Can anyone suggest to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u are behind proxy with no access provision to change the protected mode settings then use this capabilities

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
```

this will introduce some flakiness

Comment: it might work but is is WRONG: [here is why](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html) and what to do instead

Answer (score 9):

You cannot open IE browser instance if Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones OR if the browser is zoomed.

1. To resolve this, *Open IE Browser* and go to *Internet Options*
   windows.
2. Click on *Security tab* and make sure '*Internet*','*Local
   Intranet*','*Trusted sites*' and '*Restricted sites*' have '**Enable
   Protected Mode**' either checked or unchecked for all options.
3. Apply and save the settings and re-run the test code. It should
   work.

Below ***workaround*** is provided which will help you to temporarily solve the problem.

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();

caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);

WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
```

**Note :** ***If you don't have permission to change IE settings,Request you to contact your IT administrator to get the required changes done.***

- *Protected Mode* is an important step forward in *security* for Internet Explorer (IE), it helps protect users from attack by running
  an IE process with greatly restricted privileges.
- Protected Mode settings, like almost all other settings of IE, are
  stored in the Windows registry  and are checked when the browser is
  instantiated.
- The driver needed a workaround for people who couldn't set those IE
  settings because their machine was overly locked down and so
  *capabiltity* fetaure was introduced.
- It simply *bypasses the registry check*. Using the capability doesn't
  solve the underlying problem though.
- *Unexpected hangs*, *element location not working*, and *clicks not being propagated*, could result.
- To help warn people of this potential problem, the capability was
  given big scary-sounding names like
  **INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS**.
- Ask your IT support to make the changes and if still using the
  capability you are risking the stability of your code.

Comment: As i don't have permission to change IE settings.so i am unable to apply your steps.

Comment: Your answer helped me to dig into the issue I was encountering to run my protractor tests on IE.