# Getting org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException for IE Driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, remotewebdriver, iedriverserver

I am getting  org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: session null does not exist exception while trying to open google.com through IE driver.

My code is as follows:

```
public class Google {
    static WebDriver obj;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String browser = "ie";

        if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Selenium\\Selenium Prerequisites\\chromedriver.exe");
            obj = new ChromeDriver();

        } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
            obj = new FirefoxDriver();
        } 
        else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "E:\\Selenium\\Selenium Prerequisites\\IEDriverServer.exe");
            obj = new InternetExplorerDriver();

        }
        else
            System.out.println("invalid browser name");

        obj.get("https:\\google.com");
    }
}
```

Please let me know where I am missing, I am using IE browser v11, selenium webdriver v2.53.1, IEDriverServer v3.6.0 32bit.

Below is full exception which I am getting **(Please note that if I switch to selenium webdriver v3.6, then there is no issue and code is working perfectly)**:

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
3.6.0.0
Listening on port 37910
Only local connections are allowed
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: session null does not exist (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
System info: host: 'SHAN', ip: '192.168.1.6', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{capabilities={acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=11, se:ieOptions={nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, requireWindowFocus=false, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:37910/, ignoreZoomSetting=false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout=3000, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false}, browserName=internet explorer, pageLoadStrategy=normal, unhandledPromptBehavior=dismiss, platformName=windows, setWindowRect=true}, sessionId=280ec1bf-328c-42f6-8f46-e5e7a1dc47f5, platform=ANY}]
Session ID: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:316)
    at webDriverInitialTest.Google.main(Google.java:54)
```

Below are the screenshots from IE security tab.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you have done all the setting in IE like zoom level and security settings.  If not then first do configure and try

Comment: @NarendraR, which security settings you are talking about. I am new to selenium so have few knowledge. Could you please let me know for which setting you are talking about? My above code is perfectly working for chrome & firefox but only getting issue in IE.

Comment: lookout here http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-run-webdriver-in-ie-browser

Comment: can u replace below code and let me know  `DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();   
      capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "IE");
      capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);     
      System.out.println("Starting InternetExplorer........");
      System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","src/test/resources/IEDriverServer.exe");
      driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);  
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get(TestDataComman.baseURL);`

Comment: Getting same exception. I have used below code in elseif condition for ie driver.`DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "IE"); 
    capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
    System.out.println("Starting InternetExplorer........"); 
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","E:\\Selenium\\Selenium Prerequisites\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    obj = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities); 
    obj.manage().window().maximize();`

Comment: See this also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29642940/unable-to-open-ie11-driver-instance-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java

Answer (score 1):

Do it manually

Set same Security level for all zones. Try this steps

- Open Internet Explorer Browser
- Go to menu and open Tools -> Internet Options -> Security
- Set all values of zones (Internet, Local intranet, Trusted sites, Restricted sites) to the same protected mode, enabled or disabled should not matter
- click on OK.

or use this

```
DesiredCapabilities IEcaps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();

IEcaps .setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);

WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(IEcaps );
```

Comment: I have tried both way but getting same exception every time.

Comment: Strange, Let me check aganin

Comment: I have added screenshots o security tab as well in the question, please check.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from setting the Protected mode enabled or disabled for all the 4 zones, you will need to set the zoom level to 100% in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

To launch the `IE11` using `selenium WebDriver` use the `IEDriverServer_Win32_3.4.0` version and latest `selenium webDriver`. It works for IE11
You can get the IE driver 3.4.0 in the below link 
http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=3.4/

Also add the below snippet to your code to ignore the protected mode settings of IE and set the path for `IEDriverServer` in your code

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer(); 
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.
INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);    
String driverpath="src/Drivers/IEDriverServer.exe"; //IEDirver path
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",driverpath);
InternetExplorerDriver driver= new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
```