# Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones

Tags: python, robotframework

I have difficulty accessing ie using selenium+ride(3.0.2) with Python(2.7.10) where I am getting an error message **"WebDriverException: Message: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones. Enable Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones."**

I am just trying to open ie and here is my code snippet. Please note that I do not have admin access to the machine and thus will not be able to update protected mode settings. Your help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

**Code->**

*Settings*

Library SeleniumLibrary

*Variables*

${url}            http://mlipsgbvo4uapp3/gbvo/vital/Vital_AppMenu.asp

*Test Cases*

ClientSearch

```
Open Browser    ${url}    ie
Maximize Browser Window
Close All Browsers﻿
```

Comment: Check out the answer @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29642940/unable-to-open-ie11-driver-instance-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java

Comment: Thanks. But, that is for Java only. Could you please help me with exact Robot framework coding to resolve this issue. I did this, but still not working.

Comment: *** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary
Library           OperatingSystem
*** Variables ***
${url}            http://mlipsgbvo4uapp3/gbvo/vital/Vital_AppMenu.asp
${local_ie_driver}    C:\Python27\IEDriverServer.exe
*** Test Cases ***
ClientSearch
    Set Environment Variable    ignoreProtectedModeSettings    True
    Set Environment Variable    webdriver.ie.driver    ${local_ie_driver}
    Open Browser    ${url}    ie
    Maximize Browser Window
    Close All Browsers

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add examples. In addition the key suggestion in the referred answer is how to set your protected mode settings for all the zones. This is an IE setting. Has nothing to do with Java or Robot Framework.

Comment: I have already mentioned that I do not have admin access to update the settings. Only way is to bypass the settings using programs. Please let me know if you have any other suggestions/codings.